# Set ID like a string in android studio with java

Tags: android, android-view

I have always set ID of a general View in XML file. To remember the view, I have set ID with a string that represents the View. Now I want create a View dynamically using Java and set the ID there, but I don't want use a number, but a string like in XML file. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not quite following what are you trying to do. Do you have any coding that can help clarify this?

Comment: You must use a number. That's what `R.id.your_view` actually evaluates to. Though, it's not really clear why you need an ID when you have direct access to the View in the Java code, so you don't need `findViewById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`but a string like in XML file. It's possible`

for this purpose you have the file `ids.xml`, that you have to create manually under `res/values` . Its structure is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="my_id" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

programmatically, you can access `my_id` with `R.id.my_id` and assign it you your view using `View.setId`. The numeric value will be assigned at compile time from Android, so you won't have to worry about it. Just use the identifier as you would normally do

Comment: Thank you! 
This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: you are welcome. You should click on the check mark under the down arrow (to accept the answer)

Comment: I'm sorry, now I did :)